# c void pointer array printing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void

How to pass value of a void pointer array to other function?

The meaning of the function parameters is

1. void pointer to array of elements
2. array element size, e. g. `sizeof(int)`
3. number of array elements size

How can I `printf` a `void` pointer array?

```
void sorting(void* p, int sz, int n, int (*pf)(void*, void*))
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)                 
            if (pf(/*?*/, /*?*/) > 0)
                /*swap function*/
}

int cmp_int(void* p1, void* p2)
{
    if (*(int*)p1 < *(int*)p2) return -1;
    if (*(int*)p1 > *(int*)p2) return +1;
    return 0;
}

int cmp_dbl(void* p1, void* p2)
{
    if (*(double*)p1 < *(double*)p2) return -1;
    if (*(double*)p1 > *(double*)p2) return +1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = { 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 1, 7, 8 };
    int an = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    double b[] = { 4.4, 6.6, 2.2, 3.3, 8.8, 1.0, 0.0 };
    int bn = sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b);

    int i;

    sorting(b, sizeof(double), bn, cmp_double);
    sorting(b, sizeof(int), an, cmp_int);
}
```

How to pass the array value to `pf()` function in `sorting()`?

Easy way is `(int *)p[j]`, but I want to use two value type (`double`, `int`)

Comment: @iharob hmm... i think *(void *)(p + sz *i) like this will work make 2 functions is only way?

Comment: @barakmanos it occur error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269430/971127

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you know the size of each element - measured in bytes, i. e. in terms of `char` - and want to pass it now appropriately.

In order to be able to do pointer arithmetics with a `void *`, you have to covert it to `char *`.

Do it this (or a similiar) way:

```
void sorting(void* p, int sz, int n, int (*pf)(void*, void*))
{
    char * pp = p; // to be used with pointer arithmetics
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)                 
            if (pf(pp + sz * i, pp + sz * j) > 0)
                /*swap function*/
}
```

Instead of `pp + sz * i`, you can write as well `&pp[sz * i]`, as they are equivalent.

Comment: "*... to be able to do pointer arithmetics ...*" ... you might like to replace all `p` with `pp`, but `p`'s definition and its 1st occurence.